# How do I configure distinct login forms as entry points for url paths in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

On a website I'll configure 2 separated paths which will have both login forms.
I want to make the URLs pointing inside those paths to be redirected to its corresponding login form when the authentication fails.

I try to do this configuring both `SecurityFiterChain` which will use the `entryPoint` as Spring security is intended to use them.

But I only get the redirection for the first in order. I also tried defining the entrypoints as @Component extending `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityBeanConfig {
 
    @Bean(name ="passwordEncoder")
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }


    private AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint(String url){
        LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint entry = new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(url);
        return entry;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChainIntranet(HttpSecurity http, @Value("${url.intranet.login}") String entryPointUrl) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> {
                    auth
                         .antMatchers("/intranet**").hasRole("PERMIT_INTRANET")
                         ;
                })
                .formLogin(login -> {
                    login
                            .loginPage("/intranet/login")
                            .defaultSuccessUrl("/intranet/dashboard")
                            .permitAll();
                })
                .logout(httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer -> httpSecurityLogoutConfigurer
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .exceptionHandling(configurer ->
                        configurer.authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint(entryPointUrl)))
                .authenticationProvider(jwtToSessionProvider)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .sessionManagement(management -> management.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED))
                .headers(headersConfigurer -> {
                    headersConfigurer.frameOptions().sameOrigin();
                })
                .cors(cors -> cors.disable())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChainCiudadanos(HttpSecurity http,  @Value("${url.users.login}") String entryPointUrl) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> {
                    auth
                            .antMatchers("/users**").hasRole("PERMIT_USER")
                            .anyRequest().permitAll()
                            ;
                })
                .formLogin(login -> {
                    login
                            .loginPage("/users/login")
                            .defaultSuccessUrl("/users/dashboard")
                            .permitAll();
                })
                .exceptionHandling(configurer ->
                        configurer.authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint(entryPointUrl)))
                .authenticationProvider(jwtToSessionProvider)
                .userDetailsService(ciudadanoDetailsService)
                .sessionManagement(management -> management.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED))
                .headers(headersConfigurer -> {
                    headersConfigurer.frameOptions().sameOrigin();
                })
                .cors(cors -> cors.disable())
                .build();
    }


   
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Noticing what you commented I started the configuration over. First 1 of the `filterChain`s alone:

- The `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` is not working: it's created with`/intranet/login` as form url. I can access the login page but if I try to get to `/intranet/dashboard` I get status ´500´ and a stacktrace for: `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`.

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain cleanFilterChainConfiguration(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .antMatcher("/intranet**")
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> { auth
                        .anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .formLogin(login -> { login
                    .loginPage("/intranet/login")
                    .permitAll();
                })
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling ->
                        exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(intranetEntrypoint))
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Your second filter chain `filterChainCiudadanos` is never used because every request is handled by the first filter chain `filterChainIntranet`. You can see how to set up multiple filter chains in the Spring Security [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity).

Comment: A subtle difference: in sample they `.antMatcher()` (or not) on `http` object ..not (only) on "authorization" (builder) object..

Comment: I updated the post Eleftheria, xerx.